# Компонент HTML Редактор в C# или заставить адекватно работать WebBrowser с JavaScript ActiveScript

Tags: c#, webbrowser, wysiwyg, компоненты

При запуске в `WebBrowser` файла с `TinyMCE` начинают вылетать ошибки

> На этой странице произошла ошибка сценария." Ошибка: "Script error".

Лазил по забугорным форумам кроме как настраивать всё вручную или прописывать тонны правил в реестре ничего не нашел. Компоненты подобные WYSIWYG редактору платные, есть ли халява в подобном случае? Может кто-то сталкивался.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При инициализации запустить `SetBrowserFeatureControl();`

```
 private void SetBrowserFeatureControlKey(string feature, string appName, uint value)
    {
        using (var key = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(
            String.Concat(@"Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\", feature),
            RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree))
        {
            key.SetValue(appName, (UInt32)value, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
        }
    }

    private void SetBrowserFeatureControl()
    {
        // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330720(v=vs.85).aspx

        // FeatureControl settings are per-process
        var fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName);

        // make the control is not running inside Visual Studio Designer
        if (String.Compare(fileName, "devenv.exe", true) == 0 || String.Compare(fileName, "XDesProc.exe", true) == 0)
            return;

        SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION", fileName, GetBrowserEmulationMode()); // Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE10 Standards mode.
        SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_AJAX_CONNECTIONEVENTS", fileName, 1);
        SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_ENABLE_CLIPCHILDREN_OPTIMIZATION", fileName, 1);
        SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_MANAGE_SCRIPT_CIRCULAR_REFS", fileName, 1);
        SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_DOMSTORAGE ", fileName, 1);
        SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_GPU_RENDERING ", fileName, 1);
        SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_IVIEWOBJECTDRAW_DMLT9_WITH_GDI  ", fileName, 0);
        SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_DISABLE_LEGACY_COMPRESSION", fileName, 1);
        SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_LOCALMACHINE_LOCKDOWN", fileName, 0);
        SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_BLOCK_LMZ_OBJECT", fileName, 0);
        SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_BLOCK_LMZ_SCRIPT", fileName, 0);
        SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_DISABLE_NAVIGATION_SOUNDS", fileName, 1);
        SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_SCRIPTURL_MITIGATION", fileName, 1);
        SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_SPELLCHECKING", fileName, 0);
        SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_STATUS_BAR_THROTTLING", fileName, 1);
        SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_TABBED_BROWSING", fileName, 1);
        SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_VALIDATE_NAVIGATE_URL", fileName, 1);
        SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_WEBOC_DOCUMENT_ZOOM", fileName, 1);
        SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_WEBOC_POPUPMANAGEMENT", fileName, 0);
        SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_WEBOC_MOVESIZECHILD", fileName, 1);
        SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_ADDON_MANAGEMENT", fileName, 0);
        SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_WEBSOCKET", fileName, 1);
        SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_WINDOW_RESTRICTIONS ", fileName, 0);
        SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_XMLHTTP", fileName, 1);

        SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_NINPUT_LEGACYMODE", fileName, 0); // blocks setting mouse cursor by mouse-clicking inside WebBrowser control navigated web pages' text boxes. Windows 8. 
    }

    private UInt32 GetBrowserEmulationMode()
    {
        int browserVersion = 7;
        using (var ieKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer",
            RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadSubTree,
            System.Security.AccessControl.RegistryRights.QueryValues))
        {
            var version = ieKey.GetValue("svcVersion");
            if (null == version)
            {
                version = ieKey.GetValue("Version");
                if (null == version)
                    throw new ApplicationException("Microsoft Internet Explorer is required!");
            }
            int.TryParse(version.ToString().Split('.')[0], out browserVersion);
        }

        UInt32 mode = 11000; // Internet Explorer 11. Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE11 Standards mode. Default value for Internet Explorer 11.
        switch (browserVersion)
        {
            case 7:
                mode = 7000; // Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE7 Standards mode. Default value for applications hosting the WebBrowser Control.
                break;
            case 8:
                mode = 8000; // Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE8 mode. Default value for Internet Explorer 8
                break;
            case 9:
                mode = 9000; // Internet Explorer 9. Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE9 mode. Default value for Internet Explorer 9.
                break;
            case 10:
                mode = 10000; // Internet Explorer 10. Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE10 mode. Default value for Internet Explorer 10.
                break;
            default:
                // use IE11 mode by default
                break;
        }

        return mode;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

вероятнее всего компонента не видит ресурсы **TinyMCE**, т.к. скрипты
попробуйте проверить методом тыка вызов скриптов, вставив например `alert('')` в начало скрипта и убедиться в его загрузке